# Which Package to select to order hourly bare metal in DAL13 with VLANs also in input?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to order an hourly bare metal in Dal13.
I have to give vlans also as input so i am using Product_Order for the ordering.
I have tried using packageId 253 but i am getting error for itemId 50635 not available for hourly order.

Am i selecting the correct package and price Item IDs?

```
 prices := []datatypes.Product_Item_Price{ // for package 253 in DAL13
    {Id: sl.Int(50635)},  //INTEL_XEON_2620_2_40 --50635
    {Id: sl.Int(37652)},  
    {Id: sl.Int(49427)},  
    {Id: sl.Int(141957)}, 
    {Id: sl.Int(49761)},  
    {Id: sl.Int(49761)},
    {Id: sl.Int(49761)},
    {Id: sl.Int(35686)},
    {Id: sl.Int(80397)},
    {Id: sl.Int(50359)},
    {Id: sl.Int(34807)},
    {Id: sl.Int(25014)},
    {Id: sl.Int(33483)},
    {Id: sl.Int(34241)},
    {Id: sl.Int(32500)},
    {Id: sl.Int(32627)},
    {Id: sl.Int(35310)},
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The packageId that you are using is to order a bare metal monthly. I suggest you to use another packageId like 200, it is to order a bare metal hourly using preset.

To identify what items have hourly price, you need to check the ¨hourlyRecurringFee¨ attribute exists and it not null.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getItemPrices
```

For example the following item price has hourly pricing because ¨hourlyRecurringFee¨ exists.

```
{
        "currentPriceFlag": null,
        "hourlyRecurringFee": ".191",
        "id": 52227,
        "itemId": 4578,
        "laborFee": "0",
        "locationGroupId": 507,
        "onSaleFlag": null,
        "oneTimeFee": "0",
        "quantity": null,
        "recurringFee": "127",
        "setupFee": "0",
        "sort": 0,
        "tierMinimumThreshold": null,
        "item": {
            "capacity": "3.5",
            "description": "Single Intel Xeon E3-1270 v3 (4 Cores, 3.50 GHz)",
            "id": 4578,
            "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
            "keyName": "INTEL_SINGLE_XEON_1270_3_50",
            "softwareDescriptionId": null,
            "units": "GHz",
            "upgradeItemId": null
        }
    },
```

Below there is an example how to order a new bare metal hourly.

```
/*
Order a new server with preset configuration.

The presets used to simplify ordering by eliminating the need for price ids when submitting orders.
Also when the order contains a preset id, it is not possible to configure VLANs in the order.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/datatypes"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/sl"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    // SoftLayer API username and key
    username := "set me"
    apikey   := "set me"

    // Declare the hostname, domain, location, packageId and quantity for the
    // storage you wish to order
    complexType := "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server"
    quantity  := 1
    location  := "DALLAS13"
    packageId := 200 // Bare Metal Servers
    hostname  := "softlayer"
    domain    := "example.com"
    presetId := 149 // "Dual Xeon 2620v4, 64GB Ram, 2x1TB SATA disks, RAID1"

    // Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Hardware_Server object to model the hostname and domain
    // of server. If you set quantity greater than 1 then you need to define hostname/domain
    // per server you wish to order.
    hardware := []datatypes.Hardware{
        {
            Hostname: sl.String(hostname),
            Domain:   sl.String(domain),
            PrimaryNetworkComponent : &datatypes.Network_Component{
                NetworkVlan: &datatypes.Network_Vlan{
                    Id: sl.Int(11111),
                },
            },
            PrimaryBackendNetworkComponent : &datatypes.Network_Component{
                NetworkVlan: &datatypes.Network_Vlan{
                    Id: sl.Int(22222),
                },
            },
        },
    }

    // Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price objects. To get the list of valid
    // prices for the package use the SoftLayer_Product_Package:getItems method
    prices := []datatypes.Product_Item_Price{
        { Id: sl.Int(  1800  ) }, // 0 GB Bandwidth Allotment   
        { Id: sl.Int(  45510 ) }, // CentOS 7.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)  
        { Id: sl.Int(  273   ) }, // "100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
        { Id: sl.Int(  177695) }, // "Redundant Power Supply"
        { Id: sl.Int(  21    ) }, // 1 IP Addresses
        { Id: sl.Int(  906   ) }, // Reboot / KVM over IP
        { Id: sl.Int(  420   ) }, // Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account

        // Reboot / KVM over IP
    }

    // Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order object containing
    // the order you wish to place.
    orderTemplate := datatypes.Container_Product_Order{
        ComplexType: sl.String(complexType),
        Quantity:   sl.Int(quantity),
        Location:   sl.String(location),
        PackageId:  sl.Int(packageId),
        Hardware:   hardware,
        Prices:     prices,
        PresetId:   sl.Int(presetId),
    }

    // Create SoftLayer API session
    sess := session.New(username, apikey)

    // Get SoftLayer_Product_Order service
    service := services.GetProductOrderService(sess)

    // Use verifyOrder() method to check for errors. Replace this with placeOrder() when
    // you are ready to order.
    receipt, err := service.VerifyOrder(&orderTemplate)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to place order:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Following helps to print the result in json format.
    jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(receipt, "", "    ")
    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(jsonErr)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

The presets contents the same data that the control portal, see the below image.

[image]

To get the presetId you can use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getActivePresets?objectMask=mask[prices[id,hourlyRecurringFee,item]]
```

The response will be like the below example:

```
{
        "description": "Dual Xeon 2620v4, 64GB Ram, 2x1TB SATA disks, RAID1",
        "id": 149,
        "isActive": "1",
        "keyName": "D2620V4_64GB_2X1TB_SATA_RAID_1",
        "name": "D2620v4 64GB 2X1TB SATA RAID 1",
        "packageId": 200,
        "prices": [
            {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": ".399",
                "id": 176647,
                "item": {
                    "capacity": "2.1",
                    "description": "Dual Intel Xeon E5-2620 v4 (16 Cores, 2.10 GHz)",
                    "id": 8123,
                    "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
                    "keyName": "INTEL_INTEL_XEON_E52620_V4_2_10",
                    "softwareDescriptionId": null,
                    "units": "GHz",
                    "upgradeItemId": null,
                    "itemCategory": {
                        "categoryCode": "server",
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Server",
                        "quantityLimit": 20,
                        "sortOrder": 2
                    },
                    "totalPhysicalCoreCapacity": 16,
                    "totalPhysicalCoreCount": 16
                }
            },
```

I suggest you to compare the preset detail that you choose, between the control portal and the preset that you get in this response.

To get the prices for the rest of the items you can use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[pricingLocationGroup[locations]]
```

Search the item prices by the location that you chose.

Comment: I am getting following error for the above price items for package 200:
- SoftLayer_Exception_Public: Price # 1800 does not exist. (HTTP 200)

Can i get the names of required price items to place order so that i can search corresponding IDs
` {Id: sl.Int(49759)},
  {Id: sl.Int(178117)},
  {Id: sl.Int(178213)},
  {Id: sl.Int(45510)},
  {Id: sl.Int(273)},
  {Id: sl.Int(177695)},
  {Id: sl.Int(21)},
  {Id: sl.Int(37294)},
  {Id: sl.Int(906)},
  {Id: sl.Int(176647)},
  {Id: sl.Int(420)}, `

Comment: I updated my answer adding the description for each item in the bare metal order go code example, or you can choose the items you see necessary for your order, I suggest you go comparing the item with the options that there are by UI.

Comment: See this other example to order a bare metal in go language https://softlayer.github.io/go/order_preset_server.go/